# Asserting that a particular html element is a button or a tab in Cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

I have gone through the documentation in Cypress and I could not find a way to check if an HTML element is a tab.  I can write up a test to assert the text, css, etc, but I wanted to assert that a particular element is a tab.

I was looking at something like this:

```
cy.get("#enter").should("be", "tab").
```

Comment: Can you share the html for both button and tab ?

Comment: @AlapanDas Here you go, this is for the tab:

<div role=tab id=#tab-1 tabIndex =1 /div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the attribute value pair like:

```
cy.get('#enter')
  .should('have.attr', 'role', 'tab')
```

OR

```
cy.get('#enter')
  .should('have.attr', 'tabIndex', '1')
```

OR

You can just check the presence of attribute as well:

```
cy.get('#enter')
  .should("have.attr", "tabIndex")
```